# A .txt to modifiable android database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a question for you guys.
I have been working on a project application that in one part uses an SQLite database loaded from a txt file (it has about 100k-200k rows of 5 strings separated by the `^` sign).

Now my question is, since this is my first time working with databases, how does .txt import for modifiable databases work? If I understand right, it pulls all data from the txt file once and creates a database that it keeps to work on, so when I modify the database I modify the newly created one and not the txt? Does the code try to pull info again from the txt whenever the app loads, and would loading 200k 10char words every time be too much? :)

The database consists of music bands in this format: name/genre/popular[yes/no]/selected
The selected column is the only one being modified by the user (and the app for that matter). If I use the regular approach to databases with added implementation from a txt file will the selected column reset every time (do not want that)?

Comment: The answer is up to your program. Obviously the constant re-creating is not desirable, so don't write it that way, but instead put in some logic to see if it exists before creating it.  Though it will be more complicated if you could potential distribute a modified original with an upgrade the app - then you might need logic to merge the upgrade changes with the user's local changes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But how to make the app forget about the txt file until for example it gets an update? (btw, is the loaded SQLite db always stored on internal memory?)

Comment: Normally, you use your own implementation of [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) for exactly this purpose. See for example [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#sqliteoverview_sqliteopenhelper) or [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't distribute your app with a huge txt-file and import it on the users device. This takes time and is annoying.

Rather distribute your app with a pre-populated database and copy it over from the `res`-folder. You can use [android-sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to automate this.

Also, yes. The Database is always stored on the internal memory and you can't access it on a non-rooted device (unless you're using the AVD).

---

To import your txt-contents into a database, create a script or something that parses the contents and executes the corresponding SQL-queries. Again, your App should ship with the database, not the raw-file!

---

I was a little bored and hacked together a short Python-Script to read all entries from your txt-file and insert them into a SQLite Database:

```
import sqlite3
import re

counter = 0;
pattern = re.compile('^([^\^]+)\^([\w\s]+)\^(yes|no)\^\w+$');
conn = sqlite3.connect("imported.db");
cursor = conn.cursor();
# Create the Table:
conn.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE Bands (
        name TEXT,
        genre TEXT,
        popular INTEGER,
        selected INTEGER
    );''');

# Now, insert:
with open('bands.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
    match = pattern.search(line);
    if match:
            cursor.execute('''
            INSERT INTO Bands (name, genre, popular, selected)
            VALUES (?,?,?,0)''',
            (
                match.group(1), match.group(2),
                (1 if match.group(3) == 'yes' else 0)
            )
        );
        counter+=1;



conn.commit();
conn.close();
print "Imported ", counter, " bands!";
```

This will assume that the txt-file is named `bands.txt`, each value is separated by a `/` and each entry will be on it's own line. The resulting database-file is `imported.db`.

Also, I use `INTEGER` for all `True|False`-fields (popular, selected). These will then hold a `0` for false and a `1` for true.

Last but not least, the RegEx only allows "yes" and "no" for the `popular`-value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Since nothing in my list will be selected at first, I figured I'd just delete the selected column and insert zeros from code. Genres will also be represented as numbers. And, since I don't know Python that much, how do I start the code? :) (don't blame me, I am still a student! :)

Comment: Simply put what you want in your database in the form of `[Band Name]/[Genre Name, ID, whatever]/[popular: "yes" or "no"]/[selected]`. The script will set the `selected` to `0` for all entries, ignoring the contents from your file. To start the script, install python, copy the code into `sqlite_import.py` and (on a command-line/terminal) write `python sqlite_import.py`

Comment: And if a band name contains `/`? (AC/DC for example)

Comment: Then you have a problem :) You could choose another termination-char, something that's guaranteed to not be in anything. Something like `~` maybe?

Comment: I know, I said in my question I am using `^` :P But I was asking where to replace it in your script.  
Also, why must popular be yes or no, and not 0/1 again?

Comment: I updated the RegEx, anything but `^` in the band name should be fine now. The regex works with `yes/no` because that's what your example shows. You can change it by changing whats in the third group `(yes|no)` to whatever you want for yes/no. You'll have to change the if in the query, too.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I actually managed to get the txt reading working, but it was painfully slow, so I at last took your advice, converted it all to a pre loaded db and it's all working real fast now! Thanks! :)